# @AuthenticationPrincipal returns null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I setup my Spring Security application according to the reference document and after hours of troubleshooting I continue to get a null @AuthenticationPrincipal passed into my controller.

The authentication mechanism is working fine against the users in my database but still a null @AuthenticationPrincipal. I consulted several internet posts but still I am getting null.

**WebSecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider provider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/registration").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider());
    }
}
```

**Message (entity):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sweater_message")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String text;

    private String tag;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;

    public Message(String text, String tag, User user) {
        this.author = user;
        this.text = text;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public Message() {
    }
    ...getters and setters
```

**User(entity):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sweater_user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private boolean active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "sweater_user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public User(String username, String password, boolean active, Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.active = active;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isActive();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

   ...getters and setters
    }
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User save(User user) {
        User saveUser = new User(
                user.getUsername(),
                new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()),
                true,
                Arrays.asList(new Role("USER")));

        return userRepository.save(saveUser);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User findUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (findUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("There is no user with this username");
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                findUser.getUsername(),
                findUser.getPassword(),
                mapRolesToAuthorities(findUser.getRoles()));
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping("/main")
    public String add(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
            @RequestParam String text,
            @RequestParam String tag,
            Map<String, Object> model
    ){
        ...user is null
    }
```

Comment: I shared project on github https://github.com/MatveyAndrosyukk/sweater

Comment: The project uses a MySQL database so it's difficult to debug, but it looks like you're trying to inject `api.sweater.model.User` using the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` but  you want to inject `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` instead.

Comment: And how i should to change the code? As s field author use org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User? I can't do it. If i change @AuthenticationPrincipal org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User, i cant paste it in message constructor

Comment: You can look up your `api.sweater.model.User` in the controller, or you can make your user implement `UserDetails` and return it directly from `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: You may also benefit from reviewing the [custom UserDetails sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/user-details-service/custom-user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Changing **@AuthenticationPrincipal User user** to **@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails** since **loadUserByUsername** returns **UserDetails**

Answer (score 4):

If you are not sure what type should `@AuthenticationPrincipal` return, you could make it throw an exception using `@AuthenticationPrincipal(errorOnInvalidType=true)` like this:

```
@PostMapping("write")
public void write(@AuthenticationPrincipal(errorOnInvalidType=true) String username) {
    ...
}
```

And check the console output you should see the exception and have an idea of the principal type. For example:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@818e7baa is not assignable to class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` in your controller to see whether your userdetails object is stored in the right place since `@AuthenticationPrincipal` is an abbreviation for `(UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`.

For example:

```java
@GetMapping("/all")
public ResponseEntity<String> test(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthUserDetails userDetails) {
 
    System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());

    return ResponseEntity.ok("success");

}
```

If the out print is something other than the `UserDetails` object, it means that you did not set `Principal` correctly when you are initializing your Authentication in the filter class. Let's use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` as an example:

```java
// in filter class

@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Optional<AuthUserDetails> authUserDetailOptional = jwtProvider.resolveToken(request); // extract jwt from request, generate a userdetails object

        if (authUserDetailOptional.isPresent()){
            AuthUserDetails authUserDetails = authUserDetailOptional.get();
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authUserDetails, // set your authUserDetails here!!
                    null,
                    authUserDetails.getAuthorities()
            ); // generate authentication object

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); 
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "The token is not valid.");

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used OAuthentication-ResourceServer and had the same problem.
I fix it by creating my own RequestPostProcessor:

```
   public static RequestPostProcessor authentication(Authentication authentication) {
        return request -> {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            return request;
        };
    }
```